# CPLEX status 'integer optimal, tolerance', but 'Sol.find_unsatisfied_constraints(self.Mip)' finds unsatisfied constraints

Tags: cplex

When I set constraints in CPLEX I would like (not surprisingly) the solution of my Mixed Integer Linear Program (MILP) to actually fulfill these constraints. How do I make sure that CPLEX outputs a solution that actually fulfills all the given constraints. (We know that there are many feasible points that fulfill all of the constraints.)

Unfortunately CPLEX outputs a "solution" after 15 seconds (while having a time budget of 600 seconds) with status='integer optimal, tolerance'. But when we check `Sol.find_unsatisfied_constraints(self.Mip)` it tells us that there is an unsatisfied constraint.

One very hacky solution we found is to loop through all the alternative solutions (`solution_pool = self.Mip.populate_solution_pool()`) and check for each solution if it actually satisfies the constraints (with `Sol.find_unsatisfied_constraints`) and take the best solution that does actually fulfill all the constraints.

Is there a better solution? I think I am not the first the person who actually wants the solution to satisfy the given constraints.

Edit: All the variables involved in the unsatisfied inequality caonstraint are binary variables, so I don't think it can be the same problem as described here: https://community.ibm.com/community/user/legacy?id=ed9c22c9-9055-4032-a3c7-610fda705554&ps=25

Edit2: The inequality constraint we have given to our MILP is `-sum(x)<=-0.5`, but CPLEX outputs `x=[0,0,0,...,0]` as a solution. This is not even close to a solution. The zero-vector violates the inequality by a margin of 0.5, while we have use the default feasibility tolerance of 10<sup>-6</sup>. Why does this happen?